Sourcetree issue while opening even in admin mode
Unable to open the sourcetree in windows 11.
When i try to open the sourcetree am getting nothing on my display.
I tried reinstalling the same file from where i installed it before, but the result is same.
I tried restarting my system.

Go to this path and delete these files in your Windows 11 system.

Assemblies.cache
Composition.cache


C:\Users<userName>\AppData\Local\Atlassian\SourceTree.exe_Url_RandonString<specificVersion>


If you find more than one files with SourceTree.exe_Url_RandonString, then delete mentioned files in all of those folder.

